# regex to find consonants AND any 'u' after a 'q' (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex

I assume this is pretty simple, but I'm new to regexes and I just can't work it out.

I want to take a word as string, like "temple", "quiet" or "square" and find all of the beginning consonants before a vowel, but INCLUDING a 'u' if it follows a 'q'.

I have this working just fine to find all of the beginning consonants (without the 'qu' rule):

```
s = 'trouble'
s.match(/\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+/) # I assume I could replace '\b' with '^'
```

This returns `tr`, as expected.

To add the functionality for 'qu', I thought I could do something like this:

```
/\b([bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]|qu)+/
```

But that doesn't help at all.  Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Works for me. Please provide counterexample (no trouble with *trouble*, *quiet*, *square* etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, works for me:

```ruby
def beg_con(str)
  m = str.match(/\b([bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]|qu)+/)
  m ? m[0] : nil
end
beg_con('trouble') # => "tr"
beg_con('quiet')   # => "qu"
beg_con('square')  # => "squ"
```

Comment: @WayneConrad: interesting use of the `String#[]` operator, I didn't realize it had a variant for regexes.  All the same, I'll keep the existing impl for clarity.  Thanks for the pointer tho!

Comment: Thanks for the reinforcement.  I had another error outside of the regex that was messing up the results.  Your confirmation helped me look in the correct spot for the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match words which start with multiple *q*s:

```
^(?:[bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]|qu?)+)
```

However, such "words" may not exist in any known language (probably except Klingon).

Comment: Klingon is a real language. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan Yes, I didn't mean it seriously. ;)